# Is there a way to install GeoIP from source code on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, django, geoip

I want to install the [MaxMind GeoIP C library](http://www.maxmind.com/app/c), so that I can use [GeoIP as part of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/). I’m working on Mac OS X.

I’ve downloaded `GeoIP-1.4.8.tar.gz` from [here](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/c/) and run:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Without any problems. I’ve also downloaded `GeoIP.dat.gz` and `GeoLiteCity.dat.gz`, unzipped them and put them in a local directory.

Then I’ve set the following paths in my `settings.py`:

```
GEOIP_PATH = 'path_to_dat_files'
GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH = 'path_to_c_files'
```

Now I’m trying to run `python manage.py migrate` (which has a reference to GeoIP in a project I'm using), but I’m still getting this error:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just follow the same procedure and found nothing wrong

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

and put the geo unzip-ed database in django project's root dir, add the following to settings.py:

```
GEOIP_PATH = "./"
```

here is what I run and got:

```
% python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
>>> g = GeoIP()
>>> g.country('google.com')
{'country_name': 'United States', 'country_code': 'US'}
>>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize at this point this question is about 4+ years old, but I wanted to add additional details on how users of more current versions of Mac OS X—like Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)—can install GeoIP on their machines. This has been tested by me up until Mac OS X 10.9.5, but I believe the exact same instructions should work well for Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).

As far as Python/Django integration goes, I am fairly sure that if the GeoIP binary—and related databases—are properly installed systemwide, you don’t have to futz with `GEOIP_PATH` or related settings. But would be open to hearing from others in the comments if my assumption is wrong.

#### Prerequisites.

First, one needs to have Xcode installed. And since Xcode—since at least version 4.3 I believe—no longer includes the GNU versions of `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` those need to be installed as well. I provide details on [how to install `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/897316/167207). The rest of this answer assumes your system already has that setup.

#### Installing GeoIP from source.

With the prerequisites covered, you can install MaxMind’s GeoIP as follows.

Set the working directory to your home directory:

```
cd
```

Get the source code and decompress it:

```
curl -O http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/c/GeoIP-latest.tar.gz
tar -xvzf GeoIP-latest.tar.gz
```

Go into the uncompressed source code directory:

```
cd ./GeoIP*
```

Run `libtoolize` on the source code:

```
libtoolize -f
```

When that is done, run the `configure` script on the source code:

```
./configure
```

Now run `make` to compile it:

```
make
```

Then run `make check` to check all is good:

```
make check
```

Now install it:

```
sudo make install
```

Check it’s installed by running the `geoiplookup` command whose output should be something like this:

```
Usage: geoiplookup [-h] [-?] [-d custom_dir] [-f custom_file] [-v] [-i] [-l] <ipaddress|hostname>
```

Now you have the GeoIP source code compiled, but you don’t have any GeoIP databases installed for it to to use/reference. So let’s install them.

#### Installing GeoIP databases.

So we’re going to get the three (3) major GeoIP databases that are available out there with `curl` like this. Set the working directory to your home directory:

```
cd
```

And now use `curl` to get the `GeoIP.dat.gz`, `GeoLiteCity.dat.gz` and `GeoIPASNum.dat.gz` databases:

```
curl -O http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
curl -O http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
curl -O http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/asnum/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz
```

With that done, let’s move them into the proper directory for the GeoIP program to reference them which is `/usr/local/share/GeoIP/`. If that directory doesn’t exist on your system, you can make it like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
```

Now with that done, move the downloaded `GeoIP.dat.gz`, `GeoLiteCity.dat.gz` and `GeoIPASNum.dat.gz` databases into that directory:

```
sudo mv ~/GeoIP.dat.gz /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
sudo mv ~/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
sudo mv ~/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz /usr/local/share/GeoIP/
```

And decompress them in place:

```
sudo gzip -d -f /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat.gz
sudo gzip -d -f /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo gzip -d -f /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPASNum.dat.gz
```

We also need to rename `GeoLiteCity.dat` to `GeoIPCity.dat` like this:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
```

#### Final GeoIP binary testing.

With the GeoIP binary compiled from source and installed as well as having the databases in place, `geoiplookup` should work as expected. For example, let’s do a GeoIP lookup on Google:

```
geoiplookup google.com
```

The output of that command if all went well should be:

```
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, CA, California, Mountain View, 94043, 37.419201, -122.057404, 807, 650
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS15169 Google Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

After compiling it should print the library path:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Libraries have been installed in:    /usr/local/lib
```

Set the path to the `dylib` file:

```
GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/lib/libGeoIP.dylib'
GEOIP_PATH = GEOIP_DATA_FILE
```