# How to install Autoconf, Automake and related tools on Mac OS X from source?

Tags: macos, autoconf

I want to install `autoconf`, `automake`, `m4`, etc… from the source on a Mac OS X 10.7.2 machine running Xcode 4.2.1. The problem is anything that I try and install I have to rely on `autoconf`. Therefore, I am trying to install `autoconf` I get:

```
configure.ac:30: require Automake 1.11, but have 1.10
```

I try to install `automake`, the bootstrap reports:

```
configure.ac:20: error: Autoconf version 2.68 or higher is required
configure.ac:20: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal.tmp: error: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
```

Currently installed `autoconf` version: `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.61`

Currently installed `automake` version: `automake (GNU automake) 1.10`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

#### Update: Just use Homebrew to install these packages and move on with life.

Install Homebrew and just install the `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` packages like this:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
```

When I wrote this answer about 3+ years ago, it was to correct a previous answer that was outdated, link-only and vague in explanation. At that time I preferred to use raw source compilation on macOS for a task like this rather than a package manager like Homebrew because I simply found Homebrew and MacPorts to be a tad immature back then.

Now I use Homebrew (aka `brew`) on macOS as regularly as I use `apt-get` on Ubuntu and `yum` on CentOS. I would recommend avoiding compiling anything from raw source code on macOS unless you really have no choice.

***Old answer content below for reference purposes.***

---

I realize this question is about 3+ years old, but the accepted answer is a link only answer and that link is now dead. And the other answer is technically correct, but it still does not explain the actual hands-on process required to install the GNU versions of `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` in Mac OS X.

First, Xcode—since at least version 4.3 I believe—no longer includes the GNU versions of `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool`. This doesn’t mean you can’t install GNU tools on your own. And here is how.

I’ve used this process on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), 10.7 (Lion), 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and 10.9 (Mavericks) without issue.

#### Install Xcode and Xcode command line tools.

The first prerequisite is to have [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) installed [along with the Xcode command line tools](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) as well. Chances are if you need `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` installed, you already have Xcode and the command line tools installed, but just pointing that out for those who don’t have that setup yet.

Now, onto the show! Just note that version numbers of downloads are based on what is current (as of April 2015) and works well as of the time of this post. Adjust to other versions if you need to:

---

#### Install `autoconf` 2.69.

Set the working directory to your home directory:

```
cd
```

Get the source code and decompress it:

```
curl -O -L http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar -xzf autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
```

Go into the uncompressed source code directory:

```
cd autoconf-*
```

Run the `configure` script on the source code:

```
./configure
```

Now run `make` to compile it:

```
make
```

Now install it:

```
sudo make install
```

Check the newly installed `autoconf` version to confirm all went well:

```
autoconf --version
```

Response should be something like this:

> autoconf 2.69

---

#### Install `automake` 1.15.

Set the working directory to your home directory:

```
cd
```

Get the source code and decompress it:

```
curl -O -L http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.15.tar.gz
tar -xzf automake-1.15.tar.gz
```

Go into the uncompressed source code directory:

```
cd automake-*
```

Run the `configure` script on the source code:

```
./configure
```

Now run `make` to compile it:

```
make
```

Now install it:

```
sudo make install
```

Check the newly installed `automake` version to confirm all went well:

```
automake --version
```

Response should be something like this:

> automake 1.15

---

#### Install `libtool` 2.4.6.

Set the working directory to your home directory:

```
cd
```

Get the source code and decompress it:

```
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
tar -xzf libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz
```

Go into the uncompressed source code directory:

```
cd libtool-*
```

Run the `configure` script on the source code:

```
./configure
```

Now run `make` to compile it:

```
make
```

Now install it:

```
sudo make install
```

Check the newly installed `libtool` version—via the `man` page—to confirm all went well:

```
man libtool
```

On the first page of the man page there should be something like this:

> libtool - manual page for libtool 2.4.6

Comment: Great to show how to do it without using brew.

Comment: Upvoted the answer for the **old** answer not the new.  While using brew is easy, the old answer actually answered the question and is a great reference for those wanting to compile from source.  While compiling from source comes with it's own pitfalls, it is a great learning experience.  While Homebrew and Macports are great, they should not be the only answer to the question, "How do I install 'x'".  All that to say, thank you for your thorough answer.

Comment: @Buggy Thank you! I agree about learning how to compile from source, but as someone who has been floating between macOS and Linux for decades, macOS (and it’s hybrid customized BSD existence) is a unique kind of hell to compile from source on. If I am using Linux, compiling from source is a breeze even when it is complex. On macOS it is truly a headache not worth dealing with unless you have a real reason to do so. Homebrew has made my life easier.

Comment: thank you man!, I downloaded and compiled the latest version of autoconf, automake and libtool, and after that I compiled htop v3.2.1 with no problems

Comment: @armandfp Well, you should have just installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then run `brew install htop`. No mess or headaches. Clean package installer for macOS.

Comment: i had bad experiences with brew, I prefer to have more control with the installed packages :)

Answer (score 23):

Just use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). It compiles everything for you. It worked like a charm for me.

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
```

Comment: MacOSX (at least, Sierra) already has libtool. Also on Sierra, 'brew install autoconf automake' does install autoconf but then raises an error: "Could not symlink bin/autoconf /usr/local/bin is not writable." The problem is solved by SethMMorton's answer at [StackOverflow: Error when trying to “brew link autoconf”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844826/error-when-trying-to-brew-link-autoconf). Basically, you need to chmod /usr/local so it's writable by you, the user.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij I did not had this issue with Sierra. Successfully installed autoconf-2.69 and automake-1.15.1. But you're right that libtool is unneeded.

Answer (score 3):

If you install autoconf from the git repository, you will need automake.  However, if you instead download a distribution tarball for autoconf, you will not have that dependency.  You should always install from a distribution tarball, and not from a vcs.  In other words, if you want to install autoconf from source, just install it from source!  But realize that "install from source" means "install from a distribution tarball"; it does not mean "install from git".